# CorePlot - How to draw a connecting line between two plot symbols from different scatter plots within a graph

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a graph with two scatter plots. Both plots have data which was recorded over a period of time. For every data point in plot 1, there is a corresponding data point in plot 2. Said another way, Plot 1 and Plot 2 have varying y-values for a given x-value.

**I am trying to connect the selected plot symbol for plot 1, with the corresponding plot symbol for plot 2. Is there a specific API to implement this with CorePlot?** The delegate methods only ask for a plot symbol so there isn't anything that jumped out to me, and I haven't been able to find any other question here on SO from people with a similar issue.

I have attached an image to illustrate the effect I am trying to achieve.

If CorePlot does not currently support this behavior, my workaround is to add a third plot to the graph. This third plot will only display the plot points for the selected data point from plot 1 and the corresponding data point from plot 2.

[Graph with two scatter plots where selected plot symbol is connected to corresponding plot symbol in a different plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReaqW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all three plots use the same plot space, your idea to use a third scatter plot to draw the connecting line is the best solution. Its datasource will be very simple since it only needs two points when it should draw the line, or zero when the selection is hidden. Since it's a separate plot, you can use a different line style to distinguish it from the other plots, too.